# Is there any relation the number of MFCC coefficients with noise?

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition, pattern-recognition, feature-extraction, mfcc

I'm implementing voice recognition using MFCC + GMM in android device.

But what I wondering is whether MFCC feature can be slightly noisy-robust by adjusting the number of MFCC coefficients or by other things like frequency range, the number of filters, windowSize.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on type of the noise you want to be robust too. For example, frequency range is helpful to filter high-frequency noise but its hard to estimate the effect of parameter change for the task without any noise specification.